# Conditional math and GLSL

Tags: glsl, pixi.js

I'm currently learning GLSL with pixijs, and I'm seeing strange behavior with this simple conditional in a super simple script. Basically, the code asks if the absolute value of x-coordinate is <= 1, greater than 1, or something else.... and the "something else" branch fires!

To clarify, a number will be less than or equal to 1, or greater than 1, there should be no other possibility (unless I'm having a brain fart :-) )

More context: resolution is a uniform with a value of [10.0,10.0].

Can someone explain how this could be possible? The only thing I can think of is that the x-coordinate isn't a float. Is that possible?

```
precision mediump float;

uniform vec2 resolution;


void main()
{
    vec2 uv = ( gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy ) * 2.0 - 1.225;
    uv.y *= resolution.y/resolution.x;
    

   if (abs(uv.x) <= 1.0) {
     gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   } else if (abs(uv.x) > 1.0) {
     gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
   } else {
      /// this fires - WTF?
     gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
   }
}
```

Update: this is looking like a pixijs issue since when I manually specify `resolution` inside of the GLSL code it works. This is the code for setting the shader:

```
 const uniforms = {
    time: 0,
    resolution: new Point(10.0, 10.0),
 }
 const filter = new Filter(undefined, fragment, {
      ...uniforms
    });

 comp.filters = [filter];

 app.ticker.add((delta) => {
    filter.uniforms.resolution = new Point(10.0, 10.0);
});
```

Comment: what is this "strange behaviour" you are talking about? What is the expected outcome?
What is the Vertex Shader doing?

Comment: @Raildex unless i'm having a brain fart, the first two conditionals should capture all possibilities... a number is less than or equal to 1, or more than 1... there's no third option :-)

Comment: what makes you think it fires?

Comment: Can you store the value of `abs(uv.x)` inside a variable and check its value? Maybe some floating point number precision is causing something weird.

Comment: is resolution **really** correctly set? maybe you are dividing by zero.

Comment: that's totally what it's looking like... @Raildex... will update with pixijs code

Comment: A NaN is a floating point value that gives false whatever you compare it to. Since that's happening here, it seems like `uv.x` is a NaN. As others have pointed out that probably means divided by zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like *pixi.js* doesn't like the `resolution` as the name of a uniform. When I changed the name to `u_resolution`, it started to work. :shrug:

Answer (score 1):

Most GLSL implementations use some variation of IEEE floating point for calculations, and that has a concept NaN (not-a-number) values.  NaN values are persistent -- whenever you do an operation involving one, the result is NaN, and when you compare an NaN with another floating point value, the result is always false.  So you can easily have:

```
if (abs(uv.x) <= 1.0) {
    // less than or equal to 1
} else if (abs(uv.x) > 1.0) {
    // greater than 1
} else {
    // uv.x must be NaN!
```

There are a number of ways to get NaN, but the easiest is to compute 0/0.  So in your case if you ever have both gl_FragCooord.x == 0 and resolution.x == 0, you'll get NaN